# How to combine multiple rows of data of a single customer in a cell as comma separated values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, csv, pivot-table

I have a PIVOT table report like the one below:

```
Customer Name   Category  Date Met
-----------------------------------
Customer 1       Core        9
                             10

Customer 2       VIP         2
                             12
                             23
```

Can I get the following output by any means in pivot table (excel 2007)?

```
Customer Name   Category   Date Met
Customer 1      Core       9,10
Customer 2      VIP        2, 12, 23
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to do? I cleaned up your tables a little bit. You want to take numbers that are adjacent vertically and combine them into one cell separated by a comma? In a pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

This macro will do that without looping using an empty column to the right...  for reference, the formula being put into D2 and copied down is:

**=IF($C3="", $C2, IF($A3="", $C2&","&$D3, $C2))**

```
Sub ReduceRows()
Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("D2:D" & LR)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[1]C3="""", RC3, IF(R[1]C1="""", RC3&"",""&R[1]C4, RC3))"
    .Value = .Value
    .Copy Range("C2")
    .ClearContents
End With

Columns("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This VBA will do what you want, but it's not a pivot table

```
Sub test()
'define variables
Dim RowNum as long, LastRow As long
'turn off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'start below titles and make full selection of data
RowNum = 2
LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Range("A2", Cells(LastRow, 3)).Select
'For loop for all rows in selection with cells
For Each Row In Selection
    With Cells
    'if date isn't blank
    If Cells(RowNum, 3) <> "" Then
        'and if customer name blank
        If Cells(RowNum, 1) = "" Then
            'and if category blank
            If Cells(RowNum, 2) = "" Then
                'concatenate and delete empty line
                Cells(RowNum - 1, 3) = Cells(RowNum - 1, 3) & ", " & Cells(RowNum, 3)
                Rows(RowNum).EntireRow.Delete
                'since we deleted a row, go back a row
                RowNum = RowNum - 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
    End With
'increase rownum for next test
RowNum = RowNum + 1
Next Row
'turn on screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

and yes, I did reuse some of my code from [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/395126/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-excel)

Comment: I would recommend the **RowNum** variable which has no vartype (making it into a Variant by default) and the **LastRow** variable (which was declared as Integer) both be changed to LONG.  Excel 2007 could *easily* have data well past row 32657, better safe than sorry.  Because of this limitation, I never use Integer anymore, Long does the job safely. (and leaving the vartype off defaults to Variant, the most expensive variable type there is.