# How to combine values from multiple rows into a single row using module?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm looking to combine multiple rows into a single row based on a value in the code column.. I've noticed other questions on here similiar to my question but I cannot seem to extend the range..

```
Code    Name    Value A Value B Value C Value D Value E
101   Example      #                
101   Example                       
101   Example                     #     
101   Example                            #  
101   Example                                    #
102   Example2                                   #
102   Example2                           #  
102   Example2                    #     
102   Example2            #         
102   Example2     #
```

So the final result looks like this:

```
Code    Name    Value A Value B Value C Value D Value E
101    Example     #               #       #       #
102    Example2    #       #       #       #       #
```

**Edit**

This is what I've got so far, my plan was to shift the items to the row above before deleting the entire row as one row may have many items.

```
Dim RowNum, LastRow, Col As Long

RowNum = 2
Col = 3

LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
Range("A2", Cells(LastRow, 7)).Select

For Each row In Selection
    With Cells
        If Cells(RowNum, 1) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 1) Then
            For Each Cell In row
                If Cell > 0 Then
                Cells(RowNum + 1, Col).Copy Destination:=Cells(RowNum, Col)
                Else
                Col = Col + 1
            End If
        Rows(RowNum + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
  End With

RowNum = RowNum + 1

Next row
```

Comment: [this solution will work](http://superuser.com/questions/395126/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-excel/395297#395297). Start with it and see where you go wrong, then post what you have and we can help you where you're stuck.

Comment: The solution works but with one issue, I'm not able to increment the ColumnIndex value with each loop: For Each Row In Selection With Cells If Cells(RowNum, 1) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 1) Then Cells(RowNum + 1, Col).Copy Destination:=Cells(RowNum, Col) 'Rows(RowNum + 1).EntireRow.Delete Col = Col + 1 End If End With

Comment: Work with the cells(RowNum, 1) - the "1" is the column number (A=1, B=2) and just copy what is happening. Like I said, write it up and post your code in your question and we'll be happy to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Since there can be multiple items per row, will there ever be multiple items for matching rows in the same column?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply,.Yes, there could be multiple items for matching rows in the same column

Comment: That complicates things a bit. What about remaining in the position that they are in (value A stays as value A, etc)? Do they need to do that? If so, how to resolve conflicts?

Comment: My plan is to overwrite the cell above with the cell in selection only if the cell in selection has a value in it.. I don't want empty cells to overwrite populated cells in the above. Once a row has no data in it (excluding columns A & B) then delete the entire row..  it doesn't need to deal with any conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kind of ashamed of the answer you based your code on. **Backup your data and test on a copy!**

This should work:

```
Sub combine()

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer

For Each c In Range("A2", Cells(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1))
If c = c.Offset(1) And c <> "" Then
       For i = 1 To 6
            If c.Offset(1, i) <> "" Then
                c.Offset(, i) = c.Offset(1, i)
            End If
       Next
       c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works a treat! Would this work with .PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats) ?

Comment: You'd need to modify it to copy/paste or to bring cell format via VBA, so no, not inherently.