# How to combine values from multiple rows into a single row? Have a module, but need the variables explaining

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm completely new to VBA and trying to implement the excellent looking solution here by Raystafarian [How to combine values from multiple rows into a single row in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/395126/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-excel) (the revisited version). However as I really don't understand the solution, I'm struggling to run it where the column numbers, etc, are different. Please could someone explain to me what the variables refer to so that I can apply it to a different example? My problem is exactly the same - multiple rows for a single datapoint and looking to get a table with name/data1/data2/data3 all in the same row for Spotfire data analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty rough macro but

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineRowsRevisited()

'c is a CELL or a range
Dim c As Range
'i is a number
Dim i As Integer

'for each CELL in this range
For Each c In Range("A2", Cells(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1))
'if the CELL is the same as the cell to the right AND
'if the cell 4 to the right is the same as the cell below that one
If c = c.Offset(1) And c.Offset(, 4) = c.Offset(1, 4) Then
            'then make the cell 3 to the right the same as the cell below it
            c.Offset(, 3) = c.Offset(1, 3)
            'and delete the row below the CELL
            c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next

End Sub
```

---

This would be easier to understand given the above

```
Sub CombineRowsRevisitedAgain()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each myCell In Range(Cells("A2"), Cells(lastRow, 1))
        If (myCell = myCell.Offset(1)) And (myCell.Offset(0, 4) = myCell.Offset(1, 4)) Then
            myCell.Offset(0, 3) = myCell.Offset(1, 3)
            myCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

However, depending on the problem, it might be better to `step -1` on a row number so nothing gets skipped.

```
Sub CombineRowsRevisitedStep()
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For currentRow = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(currentRow, 1) = Cells(currentRow - 1, 1) And _
        Cells(currentRow, 4) = Cells(currentRow - 1, 4) Then
            Cells(currentRow - 1, 3) = Cells(currentRow, 3)
            Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation, and indeed for the original script!

Comment: @Emma if your question is answered, go ahead and click the green checkmark next to the answer that solved your question - this will mark the topic as complete

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different way as VBA to handle this transformation step.

You may try the free Microsoft Add-In [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) (from Excel 2010). It's quite intuitive for Loading and transforming your data. Basically you import the datas in Power Query, unpivot and repivot them.

First define your data as a table in Excel.

```
| Customer   | Value A | Value B | Year |
|------------|---------|---------|------|
| Customer 1 | 134     |         | 2009 |
| Customer 1 |         | 3       | 2009 |
| Customer 1 | 175     |         | 2010 |
| Customer 1 |         | 5       | 2010 |
| Customer 1 | 7784    |         | 2011 |
| Customer 2 | 515     |         | 2009 |
| Customer 2 | 1943    |         | 2010 |
| Customer 2 |         | 1       | 2010 |
| Customer 2 | 9745    |         | 2011 |
| Customer 2 |         | 154     | 2011 |
```

Put the cursor somewhere in the table

Go to the Power Query tab and click `From Table`. It will open the Power Query Editor.

Select the Value A/B columns (with Ctrl).
Right-click one of the column headings you’ve selected to pull up an options menu.
Click the Unpivot Columns menu.

Next Step: Select the `Attribute` and `Value` columns and then select `Pivot Column` from the `Transform` menu. Choose the `Value` column to Pivot from the dropdown and click Ok.

The Output will look like this:

```
| Customer   | Year | Value A | Value B |
|------------|------|---------|---------|
| Customer 1 | 2009 | 134     | 3       |
| Customer 1 | 2010 | 175     | 5       |
| Customer 1 | 2011 | 7784    |         |
| Customer 2 | 2009 | 515     |         |
| Customer 2 | 2010 | 1943    | 1       |
| Customer 2 | 2011 | 9745    | 154     |
```

The Power Query script of this three steps is

```
let
    Source= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Customer", "Year"}, "Attribut", "Value"),
    #"Pivot Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Columns"[Attribut]), "Attribut", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivot Column"
```

You can also find a step by step tutorial about unpivoting [here](http://www.exceltactics.com/how-to-unpivot-columns-into-rows-in-excel-using-power-query/)

Answer (score 0):

These are the explanations for the most important lines of the script:

---

`For each c In Range("A2", Cells(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1))`

Iterate through all the column A from `A2` to the last used cell, assigning the value to variable `c`.

As `c`is a cell, it has a row and column value, so it acts as a point of reference from where we can move using `Offset`.

---

`If c = c.Offset(1) And c.Offset(,4) = c.Offset(1,4) Then`

Compare cell `c` with cell on next row `c.Offset(1)` *AND* the cell on the same row but in column 4 `c.Offset(,4)` with the cell on the following row of column 4 `c.Offset(1,4)`.

---

`c.Offset(,3) = c.Offset(1,3)`

Assign to the cell on the row and column 3 `c.Offset(,3)` the value of the cell on the next row and column 3 `c.Offset(1,3)`.

---

`c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete`

Deletes the next row