# Issue with Excel VBA Script (Link to thread in message)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am working on writing a VBA script to merge rows if ID's match and then sum the information in a few fields and finally delete the lower row so I only have one entry per ID.

A screen clipping of the data that I'm working with. Rows 13 and 14 are an example of ones that need to be combined.

[Example Data Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAIjg.png)

I based my script off of Raystafarian's answer (latest revision) in the Q&A below:

[How to combine values from multiple rows into a single row in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/395126/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-excel?newreg=7eb2d091b49145efb42423485cefdabe)

My script:

```
Sub mergeSumDelete()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myCell As Range

'lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row

'Alternate way of trying to find the last row since I was having issues with the above
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For Each myCell In Range(Cells("A2"), Cells(lastRow, 1))
    If (myCell = myCell.Offset(1)) And (myCell.Offset(0, 1) = myCell.Offset(1, 1)) Then
        'Add up the data from the matching cells and put it in the top cell
        myCell.Offset(0, 2) = myCell.Offset(0, 2) + myCell.Offset(1, 2)
        myCell.Offset(0, 3) = myCell.Offset(0, 3) + myCell.Offset(1, 3)
        myCell.Offset(0, 4) = myCell.Offset(0, 4) + myCell.Offset(1, 4)

        'Delete the bottom row after data is merged
        myCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Here's my issues that I'm having.

1. For the line that is assigning lastRow a value, I am getting a Runtime 1004 error. Not sure what is going on here. I tried doing it a different way and then ran into another error...
2. I found an alternate way to assign lastRow a value that seemed to work (or didn't throw an error at least..) Now I get an error with the For each statement, a runtime error 5 (Invalid procedure call or argument).

Comment: With the lastRow you've commented out, instead of "Rows.Count, "A", I would use "A65536" which will always start at the bottom of the sheet and work up until a non-empty cell is found.

Comment: @Stephen `Rows.Count` works better in that it is variable with the type of sheet: XLS has only 65536 rows, but XLSX has over 1 million.  If you start at row 65536 on a XLSX file and there is more data than 65536 rows then it will return `1`  as the last row.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution/write a better script.

- Sizes the selection based off of the needs for my purposes
- Goes through a selection and attempts to find rows with duplicate values in the A columns. (In my case, these were vehicle ID's)
- If it finds a match then it will sum the values for B, C, D with the B, C, D values of the matching ID row below
- Delete the duplicate row (row below current row)
- Iterates through this loop 3 times in case there are up to 4 duplicates (my data allowed this; I tried a dynamic solution but failed. Tips?)
- Resizes the selection for removing extraneous rows of zero values

Any feedback is welcome, especially how to make it dynamic for an unknown number of duplicates.

```
Sub dataClean()
'Calls the below subs

Call compareSumDelete_v3
Call deleteZeroRows

End Sub

Sub compareSumDelete_v3()

'OPTIMIZATIONS ---------------------------------------------------------
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
'END OPTIMIZATIONS -----------------------------------------------------

'DYNAMICALLY SELECTING THE RANGE TO WORK WITH --------------------------
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim startCell As Range

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set startCell = Range("A2")

    'Refresh UsedRange
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    'Find Last Row
    lastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'Select Range
    sht.Range("A2:D" & lastRow - 3).Select
'END OF SELECTING THE RANGE ---------------------------------------------

'COMPARING "A" CELL VALUES, SUMMING IF MATCH, DELETING OLD ENTRY --------
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer

    'Loop through three times in case there are up to 4 duplicate entries, will combine all 4 with 3 iterations
    For j = 1 To 3
        For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count Step 1
            If Selection.Rows(i).Columns("A") = Selection.Rows(i + 1).Columns("A") Then
                Selection.Rows(i).Columns("B") = Selection.Rows(i).Columns("B") + Selection.Rows(i + 1).Columns("B")
                Selection.Rows(i).Columns("C") = Selection.Rows(i).Columns("C") + Selection.Rows(i + 1).Columns("C")
                Selection.Rows(i).Columns("D") = Selection.Rows(i).Columns("D") + Selection.Rows(i + 1).Columns("D")

                Selection.Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Delete

            End If
        Next i
    Next j
'END COMPARING/SUMMING/DELETING -----------------------------------------

End With

End Sub

Sub deleteZeroRows()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = x1calculationmanual

'DYNAMICALLY SELECTING THE RANGE TO WORK WITH --------------------------
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim startCell As Range

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set startCell = Range("B2")

    'Refresh UsedRange
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    'Find Last Row
    lastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'Select Range
    sht.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Select
'END OF SELECTING THE RANGE ---------------------------------------------

    Dim i As Long

    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Selection.Rows(i) = 0 Then
            Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End With
End Sub
```