# Stop VBA macro when reaching an empty row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have recently tried using Macros to simplify some tasks under Excel 2010 as I am working with unfortunatey huge databanks.

I already found the code I needed to merge duplicate rows and concatening unique data/comments thanks to this life-saving thread: [How to combine values from multiple rows into a single row in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/395126/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-excel)

The code was easy to understand for a beginner like me (I do want and try to understand what I am doing instead of just blindly copy-pasting). The only problem I have encountered is that the macro does not seem to stop at the last row, and ends up filling the rest of the excel sheet.

The desired result was obtained as seen in row 4 to 6, but starting row 29...[image]
However you can see that starting on row 29, the macro keeps ading ";" in the 10th column.

Here is the code that I have adapted:

```
Sub merge_dupes_and_comments()
'define variables

Dim RowNum As Long, LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

RowNum = 2
LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
Range("A2", Cells(LastRow, 10)).Select

For Each row In Selection
    With Cells
    'if OC number matches
    If Cells(RowNum, 2) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 2) Then
        'and if position and material match
        If Cells(RowNum, 4) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 4) Then
        If Cells(RowNum, 5) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 5) Then
        'move updated comments up next to the old comment and delete empty line
            Cells(RowNum, 10) = Cells(RowNum, 10) & ";" & Cells(RowNum + 1, 10)
            Rows(RowNum + 1).EntireRow.Delete
       End If
        End If
         End If
         End With

RowNum = RowNum + 1
Next row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am not quite sure why it is not stoping and I do not want to input a specific end row as the database I am working with varies every week.

I tried to redefine the last row as:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterData") 'enter name of the sheet you're working on
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
```

But I have noted any changes.

I would be grateful for any help!

Many thanks in advance, KuroNavi

Comment: If you know you can exit the loop, consider `exit for` to break out of the loop. Also, your With Cells statement is not being used in your code and you can consider removing it. With Cells make that when you enter .statement it will assume Cells. was written before it.

Comment: Also, if you press CTRL-END (I think that's the keyboard shortcutkey) to go to the last cell, where do you end up? I have a feeling there are stray empty rows at the bottom causing your script to go much further than it needs to go. This is common when you open an export with excel, and your data seems to be an export. Alternatively, create a new macro for one-time execution, put in the code of your last row, and simply do `Cells(LastRow,1).Select` and see where it jumps you to. Is it row 65535?

Comment: Hello, thank you for you quick response and for correctly formatting my post.
My data will indeed be an export.

I have made a clean new work sheet and copied the table on it. 

When I tried to input

`Sub test()
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
    
Cells(LastRow, 1).Select

End Sub`

I ended up on A31, which is indeed the last row. However when I relaunch my above mentioned code, I still end up with the extra empty rows and ";".(I am sorry, I am struggling with the formatting as newbie...)

Comment: Of course this happens. If empty row matches empty row, your macro does insert a ;. Row 29, 30 and 31 are 3 empty rows that are considered in your macro because Last cell jumps to 31, not 29. So you want to check if the row is empty. I'll write you up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last row is not the last row of the table, but there are 3 empty rows included at the bottom, which are filled by ; because your macro contains this line:

```
        Cells(RowNum, 10) = Cells(RowNum, 10) & ";" & Cells(RowNum + 1, 10)
```

This command basically says: join empty line with empty line and separate with;

But you do not want to check for empty lines. So your sub should be as follows:

```
Sub merge_dupes_and_comments()
    'define variables
    Dim RowNum As Integer, LastRow As Integer, EmptyCells as Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    RowNum = 2
    LastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
    Range("A2", Cells(LastRow, 10)).Select

    For Each row In Selection
        'Do we have am empty row? If so exit the loop.
        'Lets count the amount of empty cells on the row.
        EmptyCells=0
        For c = 1 to 10   
            if Cells(RowNum,c) = "" then EmptyCells = EmptyCells+1
        Next c

        'If we find more than 9 empty cells, assume the row is empty, and exit the loop.
        if EmptyCells > 9 then exit for

        'Lets continue the duplicate checking
        'if OC number matches
        'and if position and material match
        If Cells(RowNum, 2) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 2) AND _
           Cells(RowNum, 4) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 4) AND _
           Cells(RowNum, 5) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 5) Then
           'move updated comments up next to the old comment and delete empty line
            Cells(RowNum, 10) = Cells(RowNum, 10) & ";" & Cells(RowNum + 1, 10)
            Rows(RowNum + 1).EntireRow.Delete
       End If

    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Next row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I also changed the declaration of your variables from longs to integers, because you are working with whole numbers only that will not exceed the boundaries of an integer, so less memory consuming.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I can now see where I went wrong - you are a real life saver and you have my eternal gratitude!